# How to get user who added a label on a pull request in GitHub API

Tags: label, github-api, pull-request, github-api-v3, github-api-v4

I am trying to get data on the user who set a label on a github pull request, but I can't find this in the API docs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! I don't think this is possible with their REST API, but the GraphQL API allows querying for all historical `LabeledEvent` objects, which have fields such as `actor`, `createdAt`, and `label`.

The example query below should get you the first  label events on a pull request:

```
query { 
  repository(owner: <repo_owner>, name: <repo_name>) { 
    pullRequest(number: <pr_number>) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: LABELED_EVENT, first: 100) {
        nodes {
          ... on LabeledEvent {
            actor { login }
            # add any other LabeledEvent fields you want to query here
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```